# How to put proper weights to layouts in layouts

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the following Layout

```
[LLV
Line 1(30%height) : LLH[ Img1 (30% width) | Text1(70%width) ] 
Line 2(30%height) : LLH[ Img2 (30% width) | Text2(70%width) ] 
Line 3(30%height) : LLH[ Img3 (30% width) | Text3(70%width) ] 
]
```

LLV is linear layout Vertical orientation
LLH is linear layout Horiz orientation

Now 30% works good for width if I add a weight_sum=1 and Img (layout_weight=0.3) Text (layout_weight=0.7)

But If I apply the same logic with Lines in Vertical I dont see any 30% division of height

my LLH has a (layout_weight=0.3) and (weight_sum=1) both, what is the best way to do with this problem

Answer (score 1):

to proper use of weights in linear layout is:

```
<View android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_weight="0.3"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

The other view should be set in a similar way, but with `weight="0.7"`. They sum up to 1, and they will cover 30%, respectively 70% of the parent layout. Setting `layout_width="0dp"` will determine the views to respect the weight only.

Hope this helps

Comment: in order to avoid un-needed conversion , it's ok to use 0px , since 0 is zero no matter what unit you use.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this code its may help you..

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutmain"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_h1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0.33" >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view1"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.30"
            android:background="#123456" />

             <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_h11"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0.7" >


                 <ImageView
                     android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                     android:layout_width="0dip"
                     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                     android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                     android:layout_weight="0.3" />

                 <TextView
                     android:id="@+id/textView1"
                     android:layout_width="0dip"
                     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                     android:text="TextView"
                     android:layout_weight="0.7" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

       <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_h2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0.34" >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view2"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.30"
            android:background="#123456" />

             <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_h22"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0.7" >


                 <ImageView
                     android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                     android:layout_width="0dip"
                     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                     android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                     android:layout_weight="0.3" />

                 <TextView
                     android:id="@+id/textView2"
                     android:layout_width="0dip"
                     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                     android:text="TextView"
                     android:layout_weight="0.7" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


          <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_h3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0.33" >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view3"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.30"
            android:background="#123456" />

             <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_h33"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0.7" >


                 <ImageView
                     android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                     android:layout_width="0dip"
                     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                     android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                     android:layout_weight="0.3" />

                 <TextView
                     android:id="@+id/textView3"
                     android:layout_width="0dip"
                     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                     android:text="TextView"
                     android:layout_weight="0.7" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>






</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

for each LLH you should set the height to 0px .

for each inner view in LLH you should set the width to 0px.

also, please try to avoid using floating point values for weights. you can easily set it to 30 instead of 0.3 , while the weightSum would be 100.

if things still don't look the way you want, you can put a new View tag at the end of the containers, that will fill the remaining gap and don't show anything special in them.

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_weight=".33"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <View
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.3" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.7" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_weight=".33"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <View
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.3" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.7" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_weight=".33"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <View
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.3" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.7" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

That should work